# how to upload a directory with sftp

Tags: java, sftp

I am building a java web based application. To upload a directory and the files in it from my user's client to my server machine I am using a client-side Java applet which supports only ftp.

How do I upload a directory full of files using sftp and java?

Comment: I want to give a text area on jsp page where user can paste the path of local directory which he desires to upload and on click of submit button his directory is uploaded but i want to use sftp and i have already configured ftp server on my server machine

Comment: Just a quick info about ports. Ftp uses port 21, SFTP uses 22 by default [or whatever the sysad configured it]. See: http://serverfault.com/questions/74176/what-port-does-sftp-use

Answer (score 1):

"Only ftp" will not do with "sftp".  Either you need an sftp-applet or to have ftp enabled on your server.

Comment: SFTP is not just 'secured FTP'. It's a complete different protocol.

Comment: Hi  Jean-Philippe Briend, that means first i have to configure a sftp server. and are there any java api's available so that directory/file transfer can happen via sftp

Answer (score 0):

Using SFTP is a good idea, because FTP suffers from some security problems.

You are going to need to find SFTP client classes to use in the Java client applet which you will provide to your users, in place of the FTP classes you use now.

And, you are going to need to install an SFTP server software package on your server hardware, so your client applet has something to which to connect.  (It's possible your server hardware already has this package.  In that case you need to activate it and configure it.)

Finally, you need to understand that SFTP and FTP don't really offer the primitive operation "upload a directory." Your client Java software will need to figure out how to upload all the files in the directory on your user's machine.

Comment: actually i am using zehon library(http://www.zehon.com)to upload directory to sftp . and it's working fine if i am uploading from local machine to local sftp server but remote user is not able to upload a directory

Comment: i have installed openssh server and i am able to upload a file from remote machine via command line.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using JSCH aip([Link](http://epaul.github.com/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/package-summary.html)) for contributing sftp application. Jsch has no method helping upload directory, you can get all file path in the directory you want to download and then pass them to the upload method (put(....) in ChannelSftp class).